# c# use datatable in other form datagridview

Tags: database, datagridview, datatable, shared, local-database

Hi Ive searched many topics, also here in stackoverflow, however none solved my problem

This is my main form where I operate with my database and display items in datagridview

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

     DatabaseConnection objConnect;
     string conString;
     private static DataTable table;
     DataSet dataSet;

     public Form1()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
          CreateConnection();
          MakeDataTable();
     }

     public DataTable table
     {
          get
          {
              return table;
          }
     }

     private void MakeDataTable()
     {
          table = new DataTable();

          DataColumn column;

          column = new DataColumn();
          column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
          column.ColumnName = "Name of Item";
          table.Columns.Add(column);

          etc...
     }

     //this connects to my local db through DatabaseConnection.cs
     //where I got table ItemsInWorld, 
     //from where I take items and add it via InputBox to my datatable table
     //which works fine and shows all added items
     private void CreateConnection()
     {
          objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
          conString = Properties.Settings.Default.ItemsConnectionString;

          objConnect.connection_string = conString;
          objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

          dataSet = objConnect.GetConnection;
     }
     //I also have here code that show content of this DataTable table in 
     //DataGridView Form1.dataGridView

}
```

Lets say I would click on button in Form1, then Form2 would appear with another dataGridView

In this form, as I said, I would like to have another dataGridView lets call it just dataGridV that would show same items as the dataGridView in Form1, what should I do?

This is my code yet, but it only shows empty table

```
Form2 : form
{
        DataTable table2;
        DatabaseConnection objConnect;
        string conString;
        DataSet dataSet;
        public DataGridV()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateConnection();
            CreateDataView();
        }


        private void CreateConnection()
        {
            objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
            conString = Properties.Settings.Default.ItemsConnectionString;

            objConnect.connection_string = conString;
            objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

            dataSet = objConnect.GetConnection;
        }
        public void CreateDataView()
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            table2 = f.TableBackpack;
            dataGridViewMix.DataSource = new DataView(tableBackpack);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Form1` is responsible for opening an instance of `Form2`, then `Form1` should keep this instance in a private field:

```
private Form2 form2 = new Form2();
```

Then, create a public method in `Form2` that will allow `Form1` to set the table field (instead of `Form2` trying to pull it from `Form1` as in your code example).

```
public void SetTable(DataTable table)
{
  table2 = table;
  // Your code to fill DGV source with table2
}
```

Usage in `Form1` might look something like this:

```
form2.SetTable(this.table);
form2.ShowDialog();
```